# Updata maps markers with ajax/javascript using php/codeigniter

Tags: java, php, ajax, codeigniter, google-maps

I'm creating a Google Maps application. I need to load location data from a database with Ajax, so I can show these data every x seconds. I'm using CodeIgniter/PHP. This is what I got:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                 <title>Simple Map</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <style>
                html, body {
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
                #map {
                    height: 100%;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="map"></div>
            <script>


var map;
        var data;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                zoom: 8
            });


            httpCall();
        }

        function httpCall($http) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '<?php echo site_url('User/marks') ?>',
                data: { data: 'data' },
                dataType: "json" 
            }).success(function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: {
                                    lat: parseFloat(data[i].lat),
                                    lng: parseFloat(data[i].lng)
                                },
                                map: map
                            });
                        }
                    })
        }

            </script>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

the User/marks function is:

```
function marks() {
    echo json_encode($this->user_model->get_marks());
}
```

user_model get marks function is:

```
        function get_marks() {
            $sql = "select lat,lng 
from tbl_locations";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
        }
```

My error is:

```
ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Apparently I pass the data incorrectly, but what is the correct way?

Comment: Have you error in console?

Comment: Yiou use a createMarker function.. please show the code..

Comment: Not really, in my console of firefox I get : ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Not really ? .... seems you don't have JQuery in you code ...

Comment: sorry, the createMarker function was empty, i deleted it. Yes I mixed the 2 markers because I don't know how to give a value to "data: ({value:  markers})," I just don't understand it..

Comment: The var $markers in php what should contain? and what do you want assign the javascript markers used in ajax.?. show a sample

Comment: the markers contain a list of objects with lat and lng. Just to print them on the page each second. I've add the get_marks function.

Comment: The javascript markers should have a list of locations, the same as the php markers

Comment: Then you have already the list of markers in PHP and then why you using ajax for get this data? If you already have this marker in PHP please confirm so i can think a solution..

Comment: yes i have the list of markers in php. I need ajax just to update the markers list in google maps. And the solution I found on internet uses a markes object in ajax, I have tried to do it with my php object but that didn't work.

Comment: You are able to format the content of the $result in a string equivalent to a couple of number each row ?

Comment: yes, the $markers is a json object (string) like this : [{"lat":"50.8798","lng":"4.70052"},{"lat":"43.8798","lng":"5.70052"}]

Comment: but when i add the code to the ajax/javascript section like :         $markers = <?php json_encode($this->user_model->get_marks()) ?>

It doesn't work, he does not execute/run it

Comment: I must go out for diiner if you don't find a solution a can help you tomorrow.. I'm sorry. Is not difficult but need a bit time..

Comment: You shouldn't touch model from view. It skips security standards and MVC logic. Also, I think you are mixing php and js variables `$markers` vs. `markers`.

Comment: I post a first answer this could function if you have correct google maps api, map div and initial map object configuration .. otherwise we continue tomorrow

Comment: I edited my code at the original question. That's my code now. It gives no errors but it draws no markers...

Comment: thx for your help guys. The only thing I need to do now is make a ajax function that loads my data from the database. so with php code

Comment: You see somethings?, you have error in console? what's happen

Comment: I have udpdate the answer i think you should refer to data

Comment: @scaisEdge
I got an empty map. But no markers. The error is : ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: I edited my code. I'm now getting the error : TypeError: $http is not a function. Someone now a solution.. still struggling with this.